# Can I get some advice on JavaScript delegates?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, delegates, closures

I'm rusty with delegates and closures in JavaScript, and think I came across a situation where I'd like to try to use one or both.

I have a web app that behaves a lot like a forms app, with fields hitting a server to change data on every onBlur or onChange (depending on the form element). I use ASP.NET 3.5's Web Services and jQuery to do most of the work.

What you need to know for the example:

- `isBlocking()` is a simple mechanism to    form some functions to be synchronous    (like a mutex)
- `isDirty(el)` checks to make sure the value of the element actually    changed before wasting a call to the    server
- `Agent()` returns a singleton instance of the WebService proxy    class
- `getApplicationState()` passes a base-64 encoded string to the web    service.  This string represents the    state of the application -- the value    of the element and the state are    passed to a service that does some    calculations.  The onSuccess function    of the web service call returns the    new state, which the client processes    and updates the entire screen.
- `waitForCallback()` sets a flag that `isBlocking()` checks for the mutex

Here's an example of one of about 50 very similar functions:

```
function Field1_Changed(el) {
    if (isBlocking()) return false;
    if (isDirty(el)) {
        Agent().Field1_Changed($j(el).val(), getApplicationState());
        waitForCallback();
    }
}
```

The big problem is that the `Agent().Field_X_Changed` methods can accept a different number of parameters, but it's usually just the value and the state.  So, writing these functions gets repetitive.  I have done this so far to try out using delegates:

```
function Field_Changed(el, updateFunction, checkForDirty) {
    if (isBlocking()) return false;
    var isDirty = true; // assume true
    if (checkForDirty === true) {
        isDirty = IsDirty(el);
    }
    if (isDirty) {
        updateFunction(el);
        waitForCallback();
    }
}

function Field1_Changed(el) {
    Field_Changed(el, function(el) { 
        Agent().Field1_Changed($j(el).val(), getTransactionState()); 
    }, true);
}
```

This is ok, but sometimes I could have many parameters:

```
    ...
    Agent().Field2_Changed($j(el).val(), index, count, getApplicationState());
    ....
```

What I'd ultimately like to do is make one-linen calls, something like this (notice no `getTransactionState()` calls -- I would like that automated somehow):

```
// Typical case: 1 value parameter
function Field1_Changed(el) {
    Field_Changed(el, delegate(Agent().Field1_Changed, $j(el).val()), true);
}

// Rare case: multiple value parameters
function Field2_Changed(el, index, count) {
    Field_Changed(el, delegate(Agent().Field1_Changed, $j(el).val(), index, count), true);
}

function Field_Changed(el, theDelegate, checkIsDirty) {
    ???
}

function delegate(method) {
    /* create the change delegate */
    ???
}
```

Ok, my first question is: Is this all worth it?  Is this harder to read but easier to maintain or the other way around? This is a pretty good undertaking, so I may end up putting a bounty on this one, but I'd appreciate any help you could offer.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So, I've accepted an answer based on the fact that it pointed me in the right direction.  I thought I'd come back and post my solution so that others who may just be starting out with delegates have something to model from.  I'm also posting it to see if anybody wants to try an optimize it or make suggestions.  Here's the common `Field_Changed()` method I came up with, with `checkForDirty` and `omitState` being optional parameters:

```
function Field_Changed(el, args, delegate, checkForDirty, omitState) {
    if (isBlocking()) return false;
    if (!$j.isArray(args) || args.length == 0) {
        alert('The "args" parameter in Field_Changed() must be an array.');
        return false;
    }
    checkForDirty = checkForDirty || true; // assume true if not passed
    var isDirty = true; // assume true for updates that don't require this check
    if (checkForDirty === true) {
        isDirty = fieldIsDirty(el);
    }
    if (isDirty) {
        omitState = omitState || false; // assume false if not passed
        if (!omitState) {
            var state = getTransactionState();
            args.push(state);
        }
        delegate.apply(this, args);
        waitForCallback();
    }
}
```

It handles everything I need it to (check for dirty, applying the application state when I need it to, and forcing synchronous webservice calls.  I use it like this:

```
function TransactionAmount_Changed(el) {
    Field_Changed(el, [cleanDigits($j(el).val())], Agent().TransactionAmount_Changed, true);
}
```

`cleanDigits` strips out junk characters the user may have tried to type in.  So, thanks to everyone, and happy coding!

Comment: Cory, though you encountered this while working with web services, it's not specific to them. Maybe you should remove the web-services tag (and add "asp.net").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, few things:

1. Delegates are extremely simple in javascript since functions are first class members.

   `Function.apply` lets you call a function with an array of arguments.

So you can write it this way

```
function Field_Changed(delegate, args)
{
    if (isBlocking()) return false;
    if (isDirty(args[0])) { //args[0] is el
        delegate.apply(this, args);
        waitForCallback();
    }
}
```

And call it as:

```
Field_Changed(Agent().Field2_Changed, [el, getApplicationState(), whatever...]);
```

Comment: Nice, I never thought of passing all the arguments to the Field_Changed function. I'll give it a try (may make a few minor changes).  I think this will point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hey, what's the purpose of the "this" in delegate.apply(this, args); ?

Comment: It's the context object for the function being called i.e the value of 'this' inside the function. You can use whatever you want there.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following utility function that I wrote a long time ago:

```
/**
 * @classDescription This class contains different utility functions
 */
function Utils()
{}

/**
 * This method returns a delegate function closure that will call
 * targetMethod on targetObject with specified arguments and with
 * arguments specified by the caller of this delegate
 * 
 * @param {Object} targetObj - the object to call the method on
 * @param {Object} targetMethod - the method to call on the object
 * @param {Object} [arg1] - optional argument 1
 * @param {Object} [arg2] - optional argument 2
 * @param {Object} [arg3] - optional argument 3
 */
Utils.createDelegate = function( targetObj, targetMethod, arg1, arg2, arg3 )
{
    // Create an array containing the arguments
    var initArgs = new Array();

    // Skip the first two arguments as they are the target object and method
    for( var i = 2; i < arguments.length; ++i )
    {
        initArgs.push( arguments[i] );
    }

    // Return the closure
    return function()
    {
        // Add the initial arguments of the delegate
        var args = initArgs.slice(0);

        // Add the actual arguments specified by the call to this list
        for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i )
        {
            args.push( arguments[i] );
        }

        return targetMethod.apply( targetObj, args );
    };
}
```

So, in your example, I would replace

```
function Field1_Changed(el) {
    Field_Changed(el, delegate(Agent().Field1_Changed, $j(el).val()), true);
}
```

With something along the lines

```
function Field1_Changed(el) {
    Field_Changed(el, Utils.createDelegate(Agent(), Agent().Field1_Changed, $j(el).val()), true);
}
```

Then, inside of `Agent().FieldX_Changed` I would manually call `getApplicationState()` (and encapsulate that logic into a generic method to process field changes that all of the `Agent().FieldX_Changed` methods would internally call).

Comment: This looked good, up until your suggestion to call getApplicationState() inside the FieldX_Changed methods.  The methods on the Agent are generated automatically by .NET and I have no control over them.  Guess I should have mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Closures and delegates in JavaScript:
http://www.terrainformatica.com/2006/08/delegates-in-javascript/
http://www.terrainformatica.com/2006/08/delegates-in-javascript-now-with-parameters/